# How to stop spacebar from triggering a focused QPushButton?

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

Suppose I have a focused `QPushButton`:

```
my_button = new QPushButton("Press me!", this);
my_button->setFocus();
```

When this button is displayed, pressing <kbd>Space</kbd> will trigger (i.e. click) the button. I don't want this behavior. Instead, I would like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> to trigger the button.

How can I achieve this in Qt?

(Working examples would really help as this is part of my first Qt app)

Comment: Either install an event filter or subclass `QPushButton` and reimplement the `keyReleaseEvent` method. [Here is how it works in `QAbstractButton`](https://code.woboq.org/qt5/qtbase/src/widgets/widgets/qabstractbutton.cpp.html#_ZN15QAbstractButton15keyReleaseEventEP9QKeyEvent) class. You might also have to play with `keyPressEvent`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the best way is to do as ***@thuga*** said. The idea is to subclass the `QPushButton` and reimplement `keyPressEvent()`.

This may look as follows:

*.h*

```
#include <QPushButton>

class MyQPushButton final : public QPushButton
{
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        MyQPushButton(const QIcon icon, const QString & text, QWidget * parent = nullptr);
        MyQPushButton(const QString & text, QWidget * parent = nullptr);
        MyQPushButton(QWidget * parent = nullptr);

    protected:
        void keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * e) override;
};
```

*.cpp*

```
#include <QKeyEvent>

MyQPushButton::MyQPushButton(const QIcon icon, const QString & text, QWidget * parent) : QPushButton(icon, text, parent)
{}
MyQPushButton::MyQPushButton(const QString & text, QWidget * parent) : QPushButton(text, parent)
{}
MyQPushButton::MyQPushButton(QWidget * parent) : QPushButton(parent)
{}

void MyQPushButton::keyPressEvent(QKeyEvent * e)
{
    if(e->key() == Qt::Key_Return && (e->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier))
        click();
    else
        e->ignore();
}
```

This way, the <kbd>Space</kbd> event is not handled anymore and the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Enter</kbd> will run the `click()` function.
**I have tested it and it worked successfully.**

I've written this example as simple as possible. Of course, feel free to adapt it to  best fit your needs.

---

If you want it to work with the numpad <kbd>Enter</kbd> key too, you can catch `Qt::Key_Enter` too. The `if` condition would be something like:

```
if((e->key() == Qt::Key_Return || e->key() == Qt::Key_Enter) && (e->modifiers() & Qt::ControlModifier))
```

Comment: How would you do this in python3?

Comment: @CarlosMedina I was just about to say that it would be better to create a new question for Python3 with PyQt5 when I saw you already did it :) (and I'm glad to see that your question has been solved at the time I'm writing this comment)

Answer (score 0):

you can connect the slot of the button clicked to a shortcut

```
connect(new QShortcut(QKeySequence(Qt::CTRL + Qt::Key_Enter), this), &QShortcut::activated, [this]() {on_pushButton_clicked();});
```

on the other hand, you can do set the focus policy to avoid the space bar event trigger:

```
my_button->setFocusPolicy(Qt::NoFocus)
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, it will not disable the triggering through the space button.

Comment: yes, its working as intended... or it was the question to block triggering the signal from a space bar??

Comment: If I have well understood the question, the OP wants to **replace** (_"...I don't want this behavior. Instead, ..."_) the shortcut from the space bar by the shortcut you provided (CTRL+Enter).

Comment: Note that I also want to block the space bar from triggering the button.

Comment: In fact, I think it has to work only while being focused. And you did not really remove the space handle :) Actually I think reimplementing the `QPushButton::KeyPressEvent()` would be the good solution.