# How to stop spacebar from triggering a focused QPushButton in PyQt5?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5

When the <kbd>space</kbd> key is pressed, I want the button to not trigger; how can I implement that functionality? I have found a similar [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58388744/how-to-stop-spacebar-from-triggering-a-focused-qpushbutton) but it is written in [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b), how could I translate it to [python](/questions/tagged/python), but modifying its behavior to what I want?

Comment: mmm, what is your real question? Translation from C++ to python or do you want an alternative solution?

Comment: @eyllanesc Sorry that my quesion is confusing; a translation from c++ would be adequate, however if there is a simpler way that involves making a push button never have focus that is easier to do, then that is also acceptable.

Comment: Then you should rewrite your question as: I want to stop that when Ctrl + Space is pressed, the button click is invoked and instead it is triggered when Ctrl + Enter is pressed, how can I implement that functionality? In my research I have found this question but the answers are written in C++, how can I translate it to python?

Comment: Ok, the post is clearer as to my intentions.

Comment: mmm, your question changed radically, from what I understand you don't want any pressed key to trigger the button click, am I correct? If so then my edit fixes that error.

Comment: Yes, I want the button to only be activated when the mouse clicks on it; no keyboard press should activate it.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want any keyboard event that triggers the button then just implement an event filter:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtWidgets


class Listener(QtCore.QObject):
    def __init__(self, button):
        super().__init__(button)
        self._button = button
        self.button.installEventFilter(self)

    @property
    def button(self):
        return self._button

    def eventFilter(self, obj, event):
        if obj is self.button and event.type() == QtCore.QEvent.KeyPress:
            return True
        return super().eventFilter(obj, event)


App = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

w = QtWidgets.QWidget()
lay = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(w)
btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton()
lay.addWidget(btn)
w.show()

btn.clicked.connect(print)

listener = Listener(btn)

sys.exit(App.exec())
```

Comment: I'm not too well versed in Qt or python, but I don't think this answers my question. I want a button that ignores any keyPressed event. Nothing I type should focus the button and activate it.

Comment: @CarlosMedina I do not understand you, I think that you have not clearly explained what you want. Could you explain in detail what you want in addition to providing a [mre]. Your question is confusing, that a QPushButton has the focus and any key is pressed will cause the clicked to fire. Have you tested my solution?

Comment: Sorry, I miss-typed my code; runs as expected, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Setting noFocus policy for button also works. Button stops reacting to spacebar.

```
self.button= QPushButton()
self.button.setFocusPolicy(Qt.NoFocus)
```